# How I Bulkify my Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

```
trigger DistributeDataonCorplevel on test__c (After Update) 
{
  if(checkRecursive.runOnce())
    { 
   try
   {
    Boolean t = true;
    String fcst ='forecast';
    Decimal Sum1 ;  Decimal Sum2 ;  Decimal Sum3 ; Decimal Sum4 ; Decimal Sum5 ; Decimal Sum6 ; Decimal Sum7 ; Decimal Sum8 ; Decimal Sum9 ;
    Decimal Sum10 ; Decimal Sum11 ; Decimal Sum12 ; Decimal Sum13 ; Decimal Sum14 ; Decimal Sum15 ; Decimal Sum16 ; Decimal Sum17 ; Decimal Sum18 ;
    List<test__c> lst1 = new List<test__c>();
    List<test__c> NEWlst1 = new List<test__c>();
   Set<String> Corp3prodId = new Set<String>();
    id ownrid =  userinfo.getuserId();
  for(test__c dm : trigger.New)
  {
        if(dm.Product_for_DF__c == dm.corp3__c)
        {
            system.debug(dm);
            Corp3prodId.add(dm.Id);
            NEWlst1.add(dm);
        }  
  }
  for(test__c dm: NEWlst1)
  {
         Sum1 =0;   Sum2 =0;   Sum3 =0;  Sum4 =0;  Sum5 =0;  Sum6 =0;  Sum7 =0;  Sum8 =0;  Sum9 =0;
         Sum10 =0;  Sum11 =0;  Sum12 =0;   Sum13 =0;  Sum14 =0;  Sum15 =0;  Sum16 =0;  Sum17 =0;  Sum18 =0;
         List<test__c>  nwlst = new List<test__c>([select Id  from test__c where corp3__c =:dm.corp3__c and Account__c=: dm.Account__c and product__r.name!=: dm.Product_for_DF__c and OwnerId =: ownrid]);
          if(nwlst.size()> 0)
          {
           String crp =dm.corp3__c;
           Id acid  = dm.Account__c;
           String prdctnme = dm.Product_for_DF__c;
           Id endusr = dm.End_User__c;
              String query='select  Percent_of_Forecast__c,field01__c,field02__c,field03__c,field04__c,field05__c,field06__c,field07__c,field08__c,field09__c,field10__c,field11__c,field12__c,field13__c,field14__c,field15__c,field16__c,field17__c,field18__c from test__c  where corp3__c =:crp and Account__c=: acid and product__r.name!=: prdctnme  and Product__r.IsActive=:t and Type__c=:fcst and OwnerId =: ownrid  and End_User__c=: endusr  ';
                    test__c dmd=  trigger.OldMap.get(dm.Id);
                    test__c  dc =new test__c();
                                            dc.Id = dm.Id;
          for(test__c dt:database.query(query))
          {
             system.debug(dt);
             system.debug(dt.Percent_of_Forecast__c);
             system.debug(dm.field01__c);
            if(dm.field01__c != dmd.field01__c && dt.Percent_of_Forecast__c !=null)
            {
               dt.field01__c = (dm.field01__c * (dt.Percent_of_Forecast__c* 100))/100;
            }   
             Sum1 = Sum1 + dt.field01__c;
             system.debug('Sum'+ Sum1);
            if(dm.field02__c != dmd.field02__c && dt.Percent_of_Forecast__c !=null)
            {
               system.debug(dm.field01__c);
               system.debug(dt.field01__c);
               system.debug(dt.Percent_of_Forecast__c);
               dt.field02__c = (dm.field02__c * (dt.Percent_of_Forecast__c* 100 ))/100;
            }
             Sum2 =Sum2 + dt.field02__c;
               system.debug('Sum'+ Sum2 );
            if(dm.field03__c != dmd.field03__c && dt.Percent_of_Forecast__c !=null)
            {
               dt.field03__c = (dm.field03__c * (dt.Percent_of_Forecast__c* 100 ))/100;
            }
             Sum3 = Sum3 +  dt.field03__c;
              system.debug('Sum'+ Sum3 );
             if(dm.field04__c != dmd.field04__c && dt.Percent_of_Forecast__c !=null)
            {
               dt.field04__c = (dm.field04__c * (dt.Percent_of_Forecast__c* 100 ))/100;
            }
             Sum4 = Sum4 +  dt.field04__c;
              if(dm.field05__c != dmd.field05__c && dt.Percent_of_Forecast__c !=null)
            {
               dt.field05__c = (dm.field05__c * (dt.Percent_of_Forecast__c* 100 ))/100;
            }
              Sum5 = Sum5 + dt.field05__c;
              if(dm.field06__c != dmd.field06__c && dt.Percent_of_Forecast__c !=null)
            {
               dt.field06__c = (dm.field06__c * (dt.Percent_of_Forecast__c* 100 ))/100;}
             Sum6 = Sum6 +  dt.field06__c ;
              if(dm.field07__c != dmd.field07__c && dt.Percent_of_Forecast__c !=null)
            {

               dt.field07__c = (dm.field07__c * (dt.Percent_of_Forecast__c* 100 ))/100;
            }
             Sum7 = Sum7 +  dt.field07__c;
              if(dm.field08__c != dmd.field08__c && dt.Percent_of_Forecast__c !=null)
            {
               dt.field08__c = (dm.field08__c * (dt.Percent_of_Forecast__c* 100 ))/100;
            }
             Sum8 = Sum8 +  dt.field08__c;
              if(dm.field09__c != dmd.field09__c && dt.Percent_of_Forecast__c !=null)
            {
               dt.field09__c = (dm.field09__c * (dt.Percent_of_Forecast__c* 100 ))/100;
            }
             Sum9 = Sum9 +  dt.field09__c;
              if(dm.field10__c != dmd.field10__c && dt.Percent_of_Forecast__c !=null)
            {
               dt.field10__c = (dm.field10__c * (dt.Percent_of_Forecast__c* 100 ))/100;
            }
              Sum10 = Sum10 + dt.field10__c;
              if(dm.field11__c != dmd.field11__c && dt.Percent_of_Forecast__c !=null)
            {
               dt.field11__c = (dm.field11__c * (dt.Percent_of_Forecast__c* 100 ))/100;
            }
             Sum11 = Sum11 + dt.field11__c;
              if(dm.fcst12__c != dmd.fcst12__c && dt.Percent_of_Forecast__c !=null)
            {
               dt.field12__c = (dm.fcst12__c * (dt.Percent_of_Forecast__c* 100 ))/100;
            }
              Sum12 = Sum12 + dt.field12__c;
              if(dm.field13__c != dmd.field13__c && dt.Percent_of_Forecast__c !=null)
            {
               dt.field13__c = (dm.field13__c * (dt.Percent_of_Forecast__c* 100 ))/100;
            }
              Sum13 = Sum13 + dt.field13__c;
              if(dm.field14__c != dmd.field14__c && dt.Percent_of_Forecast__c !=null)
            {
               dt.field14__c = (dm.field14__c * (dt.Percent_of_Forecast__c* 100 ))/100;
            }
              Sum14 = Sum14 + dt.field14__c;
              if(dm.field15__c != dmd.field15__c && dt.Percent_of_Forecast__c !=null)
            {
               dt.field15__c = (dm.field15__c * (dt.Percent_of_Forecast__c* 100 ))/100;
            }
              Sum15 = Sum15 + dt.field15__c;
              if(dm.field16__c != dmd.field16__c && dt.Percent_of_Forecast__c !=null)
            {
               dt.field16__c = (dm.field16__c * (dt.Percent_of_Forecast__c* 100 ))/100;
            }
             Sum16 = Sum16 + dt.field16__c;
              if(dm.field17__c != dmd.field17__c && dt.Percent_of_Forecast__c !=null)
            {
               dt.field17__c = (dm.field17__c * (dt.Percent_of_Forecast__c* 100 ))/100;
            }
             Sum17 = Sum17 + dt.field17__c;
              if(dm.field18__c != dmd.field18__c && dt.Percent_of_Forecast__c !=null)
            {
               dt.field18__c = (dm.field18__c * (dt.Percent_of_Forecast__c* 100 ))/100;
            }
             Sum18 = Sum18 + dt.field18__c;
            lst1.add(dt); 
          }
          dc.field01__c   = sum1;
          dc.field02__c   = sum2;
          dc.field03__c   = sum3;
          dc.field04__c   = sum4;
          dc.field05__c   = sum5;
          dc.field06__c   = sum6;
          dc.field07__c   = sum7;
          dc.field08__c   = sum8;
          dc.field09__c   = sum9;
          dc.field10__c   = sum10;
          dc.field11__c   = sum11;
          dc.field12__c   = sum12;
          dc.field13__c   = sum13;
          dc.field14__c   = sum14;
          dc.field15__c   = sum15;
          dc.field16__c   = sum16;
          dc.field17__c   = sum17;
          dc.field18__c   = sum18;
          lst1.add(dc); 
          }
  }
  NEWlst1.clear();
 if(lst1.size()>0) update lst1;
 }
 catch(Exception  e){ system.debug(e);}
 }

}
```

Comment: Why you are doing `after update`?

Comment: be worth reviewing http://sscce.org/ -- there's way too much code (get rid of the debugs and all those field0X if stmts ) here and it is confusingly formatted

Answer (score 3):

That code hurts my soul.

Because you didn't provide any context for what this code is being used for, it took me a long time to figure out why you needed two, very similar queries. I'd normally not bother with giving an answer at this stage, and instead ask for more details (this feels rather like a 'do my work for me' type question). However, as I kept trying to digest your provided code, I felt like this particular situation has some nuance to it that isn't easily handled with the standard bulkification advice of

> Iterate over one of the Trigger context variables
>
> build collections of the fields that you use in the WHERE clause
>
> replace any instances of `field = :variable` with `field IN :collection`

**tl;dr version:**

The important things to realize in this situation are:

- Mixing `Field IN :collection` and `Field NOT IN :collection` in a single `WHERE` clause doesn't work well with bulkification. In these situations, the solution is to take things out of the `WHERE` clause, and opt to do the filtering with an if statement in a loop.

  - I'd imagine the same thing applies for mixing `ANDs` and `ORs`
- Your second query is a proper subset of the first query
- To fully extract these queries out of the loops, you need to iterate over the results from the merged query multiple times.

**long version:**

So, that said, here we go.

I mentioned that your two queries were very similar. After a long, hard, look, the only meaningful difference between the two queries is that the second one has a few extra conditions in the `WHERE` clause.

This means that the second query is a proper subset of the first query (i.e. any record from the second query is also a record returned by the first query).

It'll take a little work, but we have our first step in bulkifying your code. We can completely remove the second query by taking the `SELECT` clause from query 2, and the field names from the `WHERE` clause of query 2, and merging them into the `SELECT` clause of query 1.

Instead of using the `WHERE` clause to filter the records being returned, we'll do that with an if statement inside the for loop when we iterate over the query results. In the end, the code looks like this:

```
List<Test__c> superSet = [SELECT Id, Percent_of_Forecast__c, field01__c, field02__c, ..., field17__c, field18__c, Type__c, End_User__c, Product__r.IsActive FROM Test__c WHERE corp3__c =:dm.corp3__c and Account__c=: dm.Account__c and product__r.name!=: dm.Product_for_DF__c and OwnerId =: ownrid];

Map<Id, List<Test__c>> subSets = new Map<Id, List<Test__c>>();
for(Test__c superSetRec :superSet){
    if(superSetRec.Type__c == 'forecast' && End_User__c == endusr && superSetRec.Product__r.isActive == true){
        if(!subSets.containsKey(superSetRec.Id)){
            subSets.put(superSetRec.Id, new List<Test__c>();
        }
        subSets.get(superSetRec.Id).add(superSetRec);
    }
}
```

Please note that I've removed some of the `fieldxx__c` fields from your original queries for brevity (the field names follow a simple pattern, and I didn't feel the need to type them all out).

Now that we've removed the query from the inner loop, we can work on getting that new, combined query out of the outer loop.

The `Product__r.Name != :dm.Product_for_DF__c` is problematic because a product name we want to filter out for one record may be something we want to include for another record.

If we simply aggregate these values and use `Product__r.Name NOT IN :<collection of Product_for_DF__c>` it's a near certainty that the query won't return the results you want it to.

To work around this, we'll need to remove this from the `WHERE` clause, and instead put the field into the `SELECT` clause and do the filtering when we loop over the result set.

We'll need to take the merged query from above, and modify it. The first part of taking the query out of the outer loop is pretty standard, iterate over the Trigger records, and store the values we're interested in collections.

```
Map<Id, String> idToProductName = new Map<Id, String>();
Map<Id, String> idToCorp3 = new Map<Id, String>();
Map<Id, Id> idToAccount = new Map<Id, Id>();

for(Test__c newRec :Trigger.new){
    if(dm.Product_for_DF__c == dm.corp3__c)
    {
        idToProductName.put(newRec.Id, newRec.Product_for_DF__c);
        idToCorp3.put(newRec.Id, newRec.corp3__c);
        idToAccount.put(newRec.Id, newRec.Account__c);
    }
}
```

Next, we modify the query we got from the first step in this bulkification process.

```
List<Test__c> firstLineResults = [SELECT Id, Percent_of_Forecast__c, field01__c, field02__c, ..., field17__c, field18__c, Type__c, End_User__c, Product__r.IsActive, Product__r.Name FROM Test__c WHERE Id IN :idToProductName.keySet() and corp3__c IN :idToCorp3.values() and Account__c IN :idToAccount.values() and OwnerId =: ownrid];
```

Again, please note that I've removed some of the `fieldxx__c` fields from your original queries. If you just copy/paste what I've written, you'll get an error.

Now that we have the query results, we need to iterate over the results to perform the record filtering that we took out of your two original queries. In the process, we'll also build a `superSet` list to store the same records that your first query would have returned, and a `subSets` map to store the same records that your second query would have returned.

```
List<Test__c> superSet = new Map<Id, List<Test__c>>();
Map<Id, List<Test__c>> subSets = new Map<Id, List<Test__c>>();

for(Test__c firstLineResult :firstLineResults){
    if(idToProductName.get(firstLineResult.Id) != firstLineResult.Product__r.Name && idToCorp3.get(firstLineResult.Id) == firstLineResult.corp3__c && idToAccount.get(firstLineResult.Id) == Account__c){
           superSet.add(firstLineResult);
        }
    }
}

// We must build the subsets separately from identifying the superSet records.
// The nested for loop is unavoidable here.
for(Test__c superSetRec :superSet){
    for(Test__c subSetRec :firstLineResults){
        if(superSetRec.Type__c == 'forecast' && superSetRec.End_User__c == endusr && superSetRec.Product__r.isActive == true){
            if(!subSets.containsKey(superSetRec.Id)){
                subSets.put(superSetRec.Id, new List<Test__c>();
            }
            subSets.get(superSetRec.Id).add(subSetRec);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally!

We've now moved all the queries outside of all loops, and should have the exact same information as your original code. Modifying the rest of the code to use the list and map of `Test__c` records should be a breeze.

Instead of just simply replacing the loop collection variables, I'd highly suggest doing some extra work to make your code more [dry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).

Instead of declaring 18 Decimal variables, you can use a `List<Decimal>`.
Instead of and endless onslaught of if statements, you can reduce everything down to a single loop by putting the field names into a list.

The general form for improved summing code would look like this:

```
List<String> fieldsToSum = new List<String>{'field01__c', 'field02__c', 'field03__c', 'field04__c', 'field05__c', 'field06__c', 'field07__c', 'field08__c', 'field09__c', 'field10__c', 'field11__c', 'field12__c', 'field13__c', 'field14__c', 'field15__c', 'field16__c', 'field17__c', 'field18__c'};

List<Decimal> totalSums;
List<Test__c> recordsToUpdate = new List<Test__c>();

for(Test__c superSetRec :superSet){
    totalSums = new List<Decimal>{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

    for(Test__c subsetRec :subsets.get(superSetRec.Id)){
        for(Integer i = 0; i < fieldsToSum.size(); i++){
           if(superset.get(fieldsToSum[i]) != Trigger.OldMap.get(superset.Id).get(fieldsToSum[i]) && subset.Percent_of_Forecast__c != null){
               subset.put(fieldsToSum[i], superset.get(fieldsToSum[i]) * subset.Percent_of_Forecast__c)
           }
           totalSums[i] +=  subset.get(fieldsToSum[i]);
        }

        recordsToUpdate.add(subsetRec);
    }

    for(Integer i = 0; i < fieldsToSum.size(); i++){
        superset.put(fieldsToSum[i], totalSums[i]);
    }

    recordsToUpdate.add(superSetRec);
}
```

By my count, putting everything together reduces the size of your trigger from 169 lines down to around 74.

Comment: Thank You so much  @derek f  and sorry   for providing less info    of this your code is   very helpful for me ..

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would recomend that you create classes and then invoke those classes on the trigger.

It's not a good practice to have the logic into the trigger.

Here you can have some info : https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices
 The only thing remaining to be bulkified would be this query 
`List<test__c>  nwlst = new List<test__c>([select Id  from test__c where corp3__c =:dm.corp3__c and Account__c=: dm.Account__c and product__r.name!=: dm.Product_for_DF__c and OwnerId =: ownrid]`);

You should move it out of any for/while bucle and then store it on a Map so you can get any of them inside the bucles by just the key identificator.

I can't tell you the exact answer since i'm still a bit lost on your code, but I hope you get the idea. If you have any questions type a comment and i'll try to help you.

Comment: `for(test__c dt:database.query(query))` is also inside a for loop

Comment: You're right. Missed that one.